# how to change white screen while loading?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appdelegate

before my first class open I have white screen in my app in AppDelegate class. 
I see this white screen 4-5 sec.

How can I solve this white problem ?

This is my AppDeledate class

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ScreensaverViewController())

    //получение смс для регистрации
     if #available(iOS 10, *){
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in })
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    } else {
            let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .alert, .sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    //получение уведомлений с сервера
    let notificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

    return true
}
```

Comment: Create a launch image or (preferably) a launch storyboard to be displayed while your app is launching.

Comment: I have one. ScreensaverViewController - is my launching controller. But before its open there is white screen

Comment: You can't have a view controller as your launch screen; you need to create a launch storyboard and put a scene in it and select that as the launch screen file in your project's general settings